# While loop not breaking, using cin.ignore and cin.clear() to verify input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a loop to verify that the input grade is an integer, but when I intentionally input a char, the program does nothing. It only starts a newline upon pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
void fillvector(vector<student>& parameter)         
{
string newname;
int newgrade;
int number;
cout << "How many students are in your class: ";
cin >> number;  
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    cout << endl << "Enter student name: ";
    while (1)
    {
        cin >> newname;
        cout << "Enter student grade: ";
        cin >> newgrade;
        if (cin.fail())                                                         
        {
            cout << endl << "Grade must be an integer value, try again.";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
            i--;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            student student(newname, newgrade);
            parameter.push_back(student);
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` Read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), you are misusing that.

Answer (score 1):

> `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);`

This will make `cin` ignore any further characters you enter up to `MAX_INT`..

What you wanted is to ignore up-to the next `newline`:

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

Besides, there is no point in making a `while(1)` loop that will break in all paths in the first iteration. You can remove that inner loop.

Comment: the inner loop is there to collect the data, you see that when it breaks it's supposed to i-- (trick program into ignoring that iteration) and restate the text prompting the user to input student name again.

Comment: @PaulPawłowski for the first comment, this is weird, it worked perfectly in my test after the recommended change to `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');`. For the second comment, you can do exactly the same with removing the `while(1)` and the `break` statements.

Comment: regarding the loop I sure feel silly, i see it now :).

Comment: could you share a printscreen of what your cmd prompts you after failing to enter an integer as a grade?

I amended my code to your suggestion and nothing came of it.

Comment: We migh be using on different envs, something related to your setup. I am using Windows and VS2015, I get exactly what expected, and I can continue entering names and grades after the "error" of entering a letter as grade.

Comment: try to skip fewer chars, i.e. `cin.ignore(2, '\n');` and see what happens. If then t works, there might be a pb with your terminal's necoding of the `\n`, IDK
`

Comment: Skipping fewer chars solved the issue. I'm also using Windows and VS2015 (albeit the community version, don't know if that makes a difference).
Any ideas on how to fix it? Can't hurt being thorough :). Thanks for your help anyway!